# Hibernate mapping One class to two tables (the two tables have many to one relationship)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6
I have one entity named StudyCase mapped with a table in database called StudyCase
, I also got an other entity name Measurement mapped with a table in database callsed Measurement. Every StudyCase object can be  assosiated with many Measurement objects and the question is this. 
I would like to map both of the tables in one new entity called mergedEntity and query it using clumns from both of the tables the result would be list of objects having one to one relation ship with Measurement objects of the same constrains but will have also assigned informations for the StudyCase object they belong to.

I have made something simmilar work in spring jpa :

```
public List<MergeObject> searchMeasurement(String actualConditions)
{   
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "select  *  from Measurement  INNER JOIN StudyCase ON Measurement.study_case_number=StudyCase.study_case_number where "+actualConditions  ;
    List<MergeObject> result =  this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MergeObject>(MergeObject.class)) ;

    return result ; 
}
```

Is there any way that I can achieve the same thing using hibernate.
thanks !

Comment: I am having a similar requirement where I want to map two tables (which have one to many relations) to one class for processing the results. The tables are already creates (by third party app) and I want to take data from both the tables (i.e. in Denormalized view) and do some processing. I hope this is the valid use case. Tried using <join> but it does not give results. The HQL query generated when fired directly on DB works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

using what Hibernate Documentation says, you have to do

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

This makes a Bidirectional Relationship

Answer (score 0):

Yes Using Hibernate you can create model/entity objects like below

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="StudyCase")
    public class StudyCase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="study_case_number")
    private Long study_case_number; //You might try to use Integer of String as per your requirement
        ... getter setter
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="StudyCase")
    public class Measurement {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="StudyCase")
        private StudyCase studyCaseId

       ... getter setter
    }
```

Now using Hibernate Query You can write Query like below

```
String sql = "from Measurement as measurement "
                + "inner join measurement.studyCaseId as studyCaseId "
                + "where studyCaseId.study_case_number= :studyCaseNumber";
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
        query.setParameterList("studyCaseNumber", studyCaseNumberLong);
        List<Measurement> measurementList = query.list();
```

Hope Above example will help you 
All the best!!!

Comment: thanks for trying to help but I think you might have missed the point here ! what I asked was not how to create  one two many realationship between two entitys I asked if is it possible to create an object that will have the fileds of both entitys and will server just quering perpuse . For example let us assume that the that there exist one studycase object and 5 Measurement objects assosiated with it when I want to be able to get as result of a query 5 objects of type (mergeObject) that will have the fields of the Studcase object repeated 5 times an different values for Measurement fiedls .

Comment: sorry I am trying it just is kind of hard to explain accuretly !

Comment: hello @ Nikolis.Py ,ok i understood you point but why you want to create a new mergedEntity , when you can get StudyCase Entity(Parent) from Measurement Entity(Child),See if you want to create a MargeEntity  from which you can get  StudyCase as well as Measurement  object ...so basically you are creating a new table for storing  mergedEntity which will have foreignKey to  StudyCase and Measurement  table (please correct me if i am making any mistake ),So my question is why to create a new table(mergedEntity) when you can get same result using two tables (StudyCase,Measurement)!!!!

Comment: Well I got to have this object because I need to present them as a whole (that is not up to me) and Spring made it possible to query the way I explained  which reduced significantly the complexity of my  code so I was asking if there is any possibility that I can achieve the same thing using hibernate that I am stuck up with now.

Comment: The point was to avoid creating an extra table in the database !

Comment: but " I would like to map both of the tables in one new entity called mergedEntity and query it using clumns" says that you want to create new entity doesn't it meant to create a new table then!!!!!

Comment: actually that what i have  asked you in my previous comments and see my roll-backed answer which actually totally avoid creation of new table

Comment: I am having a similar requirement where I want to map two tables (which have one to many relations) to one class for processing the results. The tables are already creates (by third party app) and I want to take data from both the tables (i.e. in Denormalized view) and do some processing. I hope this is the valid use case. Tries using join but does not give results. The HQL query generated when fired directly on DB works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I end up using spring-jpa but in a more compact way I would say.
here is the extra code :

```
private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

I cerated a method to manually initialize the datasource :

```
public void initDataSource()
    {
    String url  = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=testdb" ;
    Properties properties = new Properties()  ; 
    properties.setProperty("username", "actualUsername") ; 
    properties.setProperty("password", "actualpassowrd") ; 
    properties.setProperty("driverClassName", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") ;  
    properties.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect") ; 
    dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, properties) ; 
}
```

and I used it like this :

```
    initDataSource() ; 
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "select  *  from Measurement  INNER JOIN StudyCase ON Measurement.study_case_number=StudyCase.study_case_number where "  ;
    List<DaoObject> result =  this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<DaoObject>(DaoObject.class)) ;
```